# Report Query for multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Getting multiple records from table with subquery joins

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total_count,
  (SELECT
     chat_box.user_id,
     chat_box.message,
     members.id,
     members.display_name
   FROM chat_box INNER JOIN members
        ON chat_box.user_id = members.id
   ORDER BY chat_id DESC LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM chat_box) AS users_count
FROM chat_box
```

This is what I have so far, I want to get the `members.display_name` from the inner join where the `chat_box.user_id = members.id` as an output along aside the `chat_box.message` and save `members.display_name` and `chat_box.message` to a variable. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but it seems like you could use something like this:

```
select u.user_id,
    u.message,
    u.id,
    u.display_name,
    cb1.total_count,
    cb1.users_count
from
(
    SELECT cb.user_id ,
        cb.message,
        m.id,
        m.display_name
    FROM chat_box cb
    INNER JOIN members m
        ON cb.user_id = m.id
) u
CROSS JOIN
(
    select COUNT(*) AS total_count,
          COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users_count
    FROM chat_box
) cb1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the query you provided was faster than my initial one. Appreciate the help and guidance. Generally speaking was there a problem with how I structured my query?

Comment: @kabuto178 the biggest issue was that you were trying to return multiple columns in a correlated subquery which won't work.  Also by using all of those subqueries the query can be slower because it must scan the table multiple times.

Comment: I notice the speed increase definitely. I need to work on knowing how to correctly access these queries and sub queries.